# What fruit and vegetable combinations provide all essential amino acids?

Tags: fruit, vegetables

Suppose one would only eat fruits and vegetables. What fruit and vegetable combinations provide all essential amino acids?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Nutrition Data](http://nutritiondata.self.com/), it's a site that gives you all the details you need to do your own research on fruits and vegetables.  It provides information on fat, protein and carbohydrates, what amino acids the food provides, etc.